# Using Numba jitclass with input from dicts and tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, jit, numba

I am working on optimizing some code that I have that is mostly contained within a single python class. It does very little manipulation of python objects so I thought using Numba would be a good match but I have a large number of parameters that I need during the creation of the object, and I don't think I fully understand Numba's relatively recent dict support ([documentation here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#dict)). The parameters I have are all either single floats or ints and are passed into the object, stored, and then used throughout the running of the code, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, float64

spec = [
    ('p', dict),
    ('shape', tuple),               # the shape of the array
    ('array', float64[:,:]),          # an array field
]

params_default = {
    par_1 = 1,
    par_2 = 0.5
    }

@jitclass(spec)
class myObj:
    def __init__(self,params = params_default,shape = (100,100)):
        self.p = params
        self.shape = shape
        self.array = self.p['par_2']*np.ones(shape)

    def inc_arr(self):
        self.array += self.p['par_1']*np.ones(shape)
```

There's quite a bit I don't think I understand about what Numba needs for this. If I want to optimize this with Numba using nopython mode, do I need to pass a spec into the jitclass decorator? How do I define the spec for the dictionary? Do I need to declare the shape tuple as well? I have looked at the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jitclass.html#jitclass) I found on the jitclass decorator as well as the dict numba documentation and I am not sure what to do. When I run the above code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: spec values should be Numba type instances, got <class 'dict'>
```

Do I need to include the dict elements in the spec somehow? It's not clear from the documentation what the correct syntax for that would be.

Alternately, is there a way to get Numba to infer the input types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spec` needs to be composed of the **numba-specific types**, not of the python types!
So `tuple` and `dict` in spec must be **typed** numba types (and afaik only homogenous dicts are allowed).

So either you specify your `params_default` dict in a jitted function, as shown [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#id2) or you explicitly type a numba dict [as shown here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#id3).

For this case, I'll go with the latter approach:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, float64

# Explicitly define the types of the key and value:
params_default = nb.typed.Dict.empty(
    key_type=nb.typeof('par_1'),
    value_type=nb.typeof(0.5)
)

# assign your default values
params_default['par_1'] = 1.  # Same type required, thus setting to float
params_default['par_2'] = .5

spec = [
    ('p', nb.typeof(params_default)),
    ('shape', nb.typeof((100, 100))),               # the shape of the array
    ('array', float64[:, :]),          # an array field
]

@jitclass(spec)
class myObj:
    def __init__(self, params=params_default, shape=(100, 100)):
        self.p = params
        self.shape = shape
        self.array = self.p['par_2'] * np.ones(shape)

    def inc_arr(self):
        self.array += self.p['par_1'] * np.ones(shape)
```

As already pointed out: The dict is, afaik, homogenously typed. Thus all keys/values must be of the same type. So storing `int` and `float` in the same dict won't work.